# Необходима ли в данном предложении запятая?

Tags: запятые

Необходима ли в данном предложении запятая и, если да, то почему?

*Перед походом в парк(,) давайте сделаем домашнее задание.*

Comment: Я бы не поставила. Объяснить смогут профессионалы. :)

Comment: Вопрос — необходима ли запятая почему — как перевести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, запятая ***не нужна.*** Предложные обороты в начале фразы обособляются в английском, в русском — нет.